Who can disable the background uploading task? (Reg: BackgroundTaskCancelledReason.backgroundUpdatesDisabled)
I was working with URLSession.upload with background config.
I came across this cancellation reason in URLError.BackgroundTaskCancelledReason.backgroundUpdatesDisabled
Docs suggest that these are triggered while background tasks are disabled. Does it mean disabled by user?
Can anyone please shed light on how this cancellation reason can occur? Who can disable the background upload (User or the system ...) and how?

The user can disable background refresh either explicitly, in the settings for your app, or implicitly by enabling low power mode on their device

Thanks Paul. In my case, My app doesn't have an option to disable background refresh. Does background refresh apply to Background URLSession upload?

If you haven't added the background refresh capability, then you won't see the setting. Background refresh capability is not required for background upload. Most likely, your background uploads are being cancelled because the device is in low power mode
